# Round decimals in Streamlit

Tags: python, rounding, streamlit

I import a csv file containing only two decimals like 1.00 or 4444.00. However, the following lines of code don't maintain the two decimals and it shows 1.00000 or 4444.000000. I want to round those decimals to only two. Please could you help?

```
with st.expander("Table"):
        st.write(category_df.style.background_gradient(cmap="Blues"))
        csv = category_df.to_csv(index=False).encode('utf-8')
        st.download_button("Download", data=csv, file_name="file.csv", mime="text/csv",
                           help='Click here to download')



with st.expander("Table"):
    df_selection["month"] = df_selection["date"].dt.month_name()
    sub_category_Year = pd.pivot_table(data=df_selection, values="amount", index=["name"], columns="month")
    st.write(sub_category_Year.style.background_gradient(cmap="Blues"))





with st.expander("filtered"):
    st.write(df_selection.iloc[:500, 0:20:1].style.background_gradient(cmap="Blues_r"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the nicest method, but

```
str(int(value*100)/100)
```

works in nearly every programming language, so in Python. Put this in `st.write(...)` and you will have the display to a certain number of decimals.

Replace 100 with 1000 or 10, to whatever your need is.

Comment: Do you know how to embed your line of code into my code for this to work? Please note, the values are in a csv file. I am not entering values manually.